# understanding java code for thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I was just reviewing some java code and I came across the below program

```
public class LengthOfString extends Thread {
    static String s;

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("You Have Enter String: " + s +"  Length Of It is :" + s.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        s = "This IS String";
        LengthOfString h = new LengthOfString(); //creating the object of class
        Thread t = new Thread(h);   //why we have passed this object here???
        t.start();
    }
}
```

I understood that it is used to print string length, but I have a problem understanding the commented line. Please help me to understand why this implementation was used.

Comment: This line is indeed redundant, you can remove it and simply call: `h.start();`

Comment: Where did you get that from? It is legal, but I have never seen that in practice.

Comment: @Teeg : i found that in some old notes, just program in single page

Comment: @KaranMer Ah ok. Strange. Well you're correct to wonder about that line; as alfasin said, it is redundant. As user3294343 pointed out, you typically see that with objects that implement `Runnable`. The runnable is passed to the thread, and you can call `start` on the new thread object. Suresh's answer has a lot of good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in java, there are [2 ways to create a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) .

- Provide a Runnable object. The Runnable interface defines a single
  method, run, meant to contain the code executed in the thread. The
  Runnable object is passed to the Thread constructor.
- Subclass Thread. The Thread class itself implements Runnable, though
  its run method does nothing. An application can subclass Thread,
  providing its own implementation of run.

You chosen the second one and you can simply write

```
new LengthOfString().start();
```

instead

```
LengthOfString h=new LengthOfString(); //creating the object of class

Thread t=new Thread(h);   //why we have passed this object here???

 t.start();
```

**Edit:**

Thread class have a constructor [`public Thread(Runnable target)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), that it takes `Runnable`  type as a parameter and when you pass that to thread class it  calls the implementation of `run()`  method when you start that thread.

Comment: @KaranMer Edited little bit.

Comment: Its written 'Extended thread' near this, is there anything like extended thread?

Comment: @KaranMer Extended thread in the sense `LengthOfString extends Thread`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need the Thread t=new Thread(h) line, because LengthOfString extends Thread.  Many times though, you implement the Runnable Interface.  In that case, you need to create a Thread object with a Runnable argument in the constructor, because Runnable Objects dont have a start methods

Comment: Thread t=new Thread(h)  returns a Thread object that wraps a LengthOfString Object.  It essentially treats it like a Runnable Object, only calling the run method.

Comment: so i didn't need to write what?

Comment: All you needed was LenghtOfString h=new LengthOfString();  h.start();